# Cardinality of sets, questions wrong or I'm reading it wrong?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

Is it me or is this question wrong?

I keep books, I have 40 books. 11 are comedy, 20 are horror, and 18 are fiction. 3 are horror and comedy, 6 are horror and fiction, and 2 are comedy and fiction. How many are fiction and comedy, but not horror?

Wouldn't the answer just be 2? If not could someone explain?

Comment: Check the horror and fiction section, there might be a math book there, and you can find the answer on your own! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If $C$ is the set of comedy books, $H$ the set of horror books, and $F$ the set of fiction books, then

$$|C\cup H\cup F|=|C|+|H|+|F|-\left(|C\cap H|+|H\cap F|+|C\cap F|\right)+|C\cap H\cap F|$$

by the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), so

$$40=11+20+18-(3+6+2)+|C\cap H\cap F|\;,$$

and $|C\cap H\cap F|=40-49+11=2$. That is, there are $2$ books that are in all three categories. This means that both of the books that are comedy and fiction must also be horror, so there are **no** books that are fiction and comedy but not horror.

Comment: Ah Okay this makes sense, thank you!

Comment: @luke: You’re welcome!

Comment: I just realised, wouldn't |C∩H∩F| be Comedy, Horror and fiction? Not fiction and comedy, but not horror?

Comment: @luke: Yes, when I was writing that I forgot which set we were after. Fixed now: there are **no** such books. (I taught this stuff for so long that I tend to expect the standard problems, and this one is a little more interesting.)

Comment: Thankyou very much, you've been very helpful!

Comment: @luke: You’re very welcome.